# RAPI Approach: 1 static instance for the entire winforms app vs create,connect,dispose

Tags: compact-framework, opennetcf, rapi

In many places in our application we have code like this:

```
using(RAPI rapi = new RAPI())
{
  bool connected = TryToConnectWithTimeout(rapi);
  if(connected)
    DoSomethingWithRapi(rapi);
}
```

This has worked well so far.
We never have more than 1 rapi instance at a time.  Until now:

But now we want to listen for the connect event on rapi.
We are doing it like this:

```
void StartMonitoringRapiConnection()
{
_rapi = new RAPI();
_rapi.RAPIConnected += new RAPIConnectedHandler(_rapi_RAPIConnected);
_rapi.RAPIDisconnected += new RAPIConnectedHandler(_rapi_RAPIDisconnected);
_rapi.Connect(false,-1);
}

    private void _rapi_RAPIConnected()
    {
    DoWorkWhenRapiConnects();
    }
    private void _rapi_RAPIDisconnected()
    {
        //Listen for the next time that rapi connects
        _rapi.Connect(false,-1);
        DoWorkWhenRapiDisconnects();
    }
```

"StartMonitoringRapiConnection" works pretty well as long as I do not start to new up and connect other RAPI objects.  But once I start newing up other RAPI objects, the connect/disconnect events seem to fire out of order.

Would it work better to have just 1 static instance of RAPI for the entire app?  Do you have any other advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, RAPI is a single connection between the PC and the device.  It doesn't make sense for your app to even support multiple connections.  I'd make a [Singleton class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998558.aspx) that wraps up the RAPI calls and makes all of your calls for you so that everyone that needs to talk to the device goes through that one class.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Since RAPI object was iDisposable, we might have tried the using paradigm. thank you for putting things into perspective.